# TypeScript call function with Rest Parameters from another with Rest Parameters

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript it is possible to declare a function with "Rest Parameters":

```
function test1(p1: string, ...p2: string[]) {
    // Do something
}
```

Suppose that I declared another function that called `test1`:

```
function test2(p1: string, ...p2: string[]) {
    test1(p1, p2);  // Does not compile
}
```

The compiler produces this message:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target:
>      Could not apply type 'string' to argument 2 which is of type 'string[]'.

How can `test2` call `test1` will the supplied arguments?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the [Spread Operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/1931). It should allow for the same effect as in [Jeffery's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20763796/81595) but has a more concise syntax.

```
function test2(p1: string, ...p2: string[]) {
    test1(...arguments);
}
```

Comment: This really addresses the issue. As the spread ... notation is used to call test2, it is much clearer calling test1 with the same notation test1(...arguments)

Answer (score 12):

There's no way to pass p1 and p2 to test1 from test2.  But you could do this:

```
function test2(p1: string, ...p2: string[]): void {
    test1.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

That's making using of [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object.

If you don't like the arguments object or you don't want all the arguments passed in exactly the same order you can do something like this:

```
function test2(p1: string, ...p2: string[]) {
    test1.apply(this, [p1].concat(p2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it doesn't compile as you are doing wrong thing. Here is [the right way](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20test1%28p1%3A%20string%2C%20...p2%3A%20string%5B%5D%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Do%20something%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test2%28p1%3A%20string%2C%20...p2%3A%20string%5B%5D%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test1%28p1%2C%20...p2%29%3B%0D%0A%7D):

```
function test1(p1: string, ...p2: string[]) {
    // Do something
}

function test2(p1: string, ...p2: string[]) {
    test1(p1, ...p2);
}
```